# Eclipse+Android SDK на KDE?

Tags: android, ubuntu, eclipse, kde

Всем привет.

Хочу начать учиться кодить под Android на практике, но всё никак не даётся мне установка и настройка `IDE`.

Сначала установил `Android Studio`. Но мне для неё не хватает мощности ПК. Всё ужасно виснет и ошибки появляются на ровном месте из-за нехватки производительности на 64-битной семёрке.

В `Kubuntu` то же самое.

Решил перейти на `Eclipse`. Но она у меня упорно отказывается работать на винде.

Гуглил. Методы решения ошибок из гугла ничего не дали.
Переустановил, но стало только хуже.
Опять два часа гуглил ошибки, но это не привело ни к какому положительному результату. `AVD` просто не запускался на пустом проекте.

Загуглил, есть ли `Eclipse` под кеды. Оказалось что есть. Установил, но вижу чистую среду для разработки под саму `Java`, а не под `Android`.

**Вопросы:**

1. Где `SDK manager`?
2. Где `AVD Manager`?
3. Что нужно установить и прописать чтобы увидеть привычную мне среду разработки под Android? Гуглил, но там ничего толкового не пишут, т.к. в основном про винду.

Помогите запустить HelloWorld спустя 2 недели возни с `IDE` :(

**P.S.** Пробовал по [этому](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu) гайду, но возникает проблема на 6-ом шаге. Терминал говорит, что команды `android` не существует.

Comment: Опишите параметры компьютера, пожалуйста

Comment: приведите содержимое  Вашего .bashrc

Comment: Параметры компьютера: 4гб оперативной памяти(ddr3) и двухъядерный камень с частотой 1,8.

Comment: Сделал всё по [этой](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/eclipse) инструкции, но всё равно не вижу в Эклипсе возможности создания андроид-проекта.

Comment: `Android Studio 2.1` устанавливал недавно на нетбук. 2Гб оперативы и celeron 1.8 2 ядра, ОС `lubuntu 32bit` . `IDE` тупила, но работала. Единственный минус помимо тупезны - ариведерчи эмулятор. Использовал телефон для тестов. Почему именно `Eclipse`?

Comment: @Chubatiy тупящая IDE постоянно раздражает и не даёт сконцентрироваться на разработке и обучении. Почему Eclipse? Потому, что других IDE кроме Android Studio и Eclise для создания HelloWorld'ов под Android я не знаю.